# AngularJS warn user if added field is pristine (not required)

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, warnings

I'm wondering if someone could help me with this one:

I have a form with some fields already shown in the browser (title, dates...).  Those are required (with the "required" attribute)

But the thing is that the user will have a choice to "add a subtitle"

For good UX, if the field is left blank, I would like him to be warn if he choose to add a subtitle (by clicking on the link showing that new field)  but I don't necessarily want that field required, only a warning like "you asked for a subtitle field but you haven't specified any...".

What would be the best practice for that kind of implementation in AngularJS?

EDIT: I need this for a field in a ng-repeat... I created this:

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="subtitle in spectacle.subtitles">
    <data-ng-form name="subtitleForm">
        <label for="txtSubtitle" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sous-titre {{ $index + 1 }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSubtitle" name="txtSubtitle" data-ng-model="subtitle.value">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="" data-ng-click="remove(spectacle.subtitles, $index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></span>
            </div>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="!subtitleForm.txtSubtitle.$pristine && subtitleForm.txtSubtitle.$error.blur"><p class="text-danger">You forgot the subtitle</p></span>
            <a href="" data-ng-show="$last && spectacle.subtitles.length < 3" data-ng-click="addNewSubtitle()">Ajouter un sous-titre</a>
        </div>
    </data-ng-form>
</div>
```

But the controller part cannot read property 'txtSubtitle' of undefined
Controller:

```
$scope.saveSpectacle = function() {
    console.log('HI');
    $scope.subtitleForm.txtSubtitle.$pristine = false;
    $scope.subtitleForm.txtSubtitle.$error.blur = true;
    //s$scope.spectacle = {};
};
```

Thanks a lot

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

you can add the error message, to your field, with bootstrap like this :

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show="!formName.subtitle.$pristine && formName.subtitle.$error.blur"><p class="text-danger">You forgot the subtitle</p></span>
```

when the user click to confirm you can active the error

```
$scope.formName.subtitle`.$pristine = false;
$scope.formName.subtitle.$error.blur = true;
```

or check is value is null

```
$scope.formName.subtitle === ""
```

It's not required, but will detect if the user left the field blank, and you can also active the error even if the user didn't "dirty" the field

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but I've edited my question because it is used in a ng-form but my controller can't see the field.

Comment: Just want to add again that I've edited my question:  It totally works for a single field but I can't figure out how to target fields in a sub-form (ng-form)

I'm using ng-form name=subtitleForm, my input is like the following:
`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="subtitle" name="subtitle" data-ng-model="subtitle.value">`  and I want to check for each of the generated subtitle fields (3 subtitles max) if one of them is created, but empty.